# Original Hoare Logic termination paper

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, pl.programming-languages, program-verification, program-logic

I'm looking for the original paper where Hoare (or someone else I suppose) discusses termination (Total Correctness). Or any other early work on termination for "vanilla" Hoare logic (I suppose by that I mean a HL for a C-like toy language).

I've had a look at [*Axiomatic basis for Computer Programs*](http://www.spatial.maine.edu/~worboys/processes/hoare%20axiomatic.pdf) (PDF) (which seems to be essentially Hoare logic of the partial correctness flavour) and
*A note on the for rule*, which mentions proof of a while rule, but can't seem to find the missing link; a paper on termination/the while rule/Total correctness.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You probably want

- Manna, Pnueli, [Axiomatic Approach to Total Correctness of Programs](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Axiomatic%20approach%20to%20total%20correctness%20of%20programs%20stanford%20pdf), 1973

Answer (score 4):

There is also a three-page paper by Turing that uses ranking functions to give a correctness proof. His paper is completely readable by modern standards and extremely prescient.

> [Checking a large routine](http://www.turingarchive.org/browse.php/B/8), Alan Turing, Report of a Conference on High Speed Automatic Calculating Machines, pp.67-69, 1949.